# Search with multiple criteria using method GET

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created a code to do a search with multi-criteria but it only works if all fields are filled in the form, and if a field is empty, the query return zero result. How can I solve this ?

**Controller:**

```
public function listSearchAction($page, Request $request)
{

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');


    $name = $request->query->get('name');
    $city = $request->query->get('city');

    $qb = $em->getRepository('ProjectAgenceBundle:Agence')->getListSearchAgencesFrontend($name, $city); 

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $qb,
    $request->query->get('page', $page),10);

    }


    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Agence:agence-search-list-view.html.twig',array(
    'pagination' => $pagination,
    'mode'=> $mode,
    ));
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public function getListSearchAgencesFrontend($name, $city)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.logo', 'l')
        ->addSelect('l')
        ->Where('a.enabled = 1')
        ->andWhere('a.city = :city')
        ->setParameter('city', $city)
        ->andWhere('a.name LIKE :name')
        ->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%');

    return $qb;

}
```

**form.twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('frontend_agences_list_search') }}" method="get" name="left_search">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                          {{ form_widget(left_form_search.name) }}
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                    <label>City</label>
                 <div class="selector">
                    {{ form_widget(left_form_search.city) }}
                 </div>
               </div>
               {{ form_rest(left_form_search) }}
               <br />
              <button type="submit" class="btn-medium icon-check uppercase full-width">Search</button>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your parameters aren't empty before adding conditions to your query.

```
public function getListSearchAgencesFrontend($name = NULL, $city = NULL)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.logo', 'l')
        ->addSelect('l')
        ->Where('a.enabled = 1');
    if (!empty($city)) {
        $qb->andWhere('a.city = :city')
            ->setParameter('city', $city);
    }
    if (!empty($name)) {
        $qb->andWhere('a.name LIKE :name')
            ->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%');
    }

    return $qb;

}
```

**Updated** : use `!empty()` rather than `!== NULL`

Comment: Thank you, It doesn't work correctly first time , so I have changed `!== NULL` by `!empty` an now it works fine. if you want to modify it in the response
`if (!empty($city) ) {
         $qb->andWhere('a.city = :city')
               ->setParameter('city', $city);
     }
     if (!empty($name)) {
         $qb->andWhere('a.name LIKE :name')
               ->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%');
     }`